# Custom ul bullet with pseudo-selector and alignment

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I made a custom bullet for ul with pseudo-selector. But I want the link text position to be align inside. How do I do that? Here's the link to the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bodyfarmer/13q91433/1/

Css:

```
ul {
/*  list-style-position: outside; */    
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    list-style: none; 
}

li:before {
    content: "\00BB";
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here </li>
    <li>Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want the same behavior that: list-style-position: outside; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it as the follows, and adjust `-1em` if necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/dyd9topy/

```css
ul {  
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    list-style: none; 
}
li:before {
    content: "\00BB";
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here </li>
    <li>Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here Link text here </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that is better make this with position absolute in `:before`. That way:

```
li{
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    content: "\00BB";
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/13q91433/4/)

Comment: Oh, I was just about to post the same.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer works, although a slightly different alternative is:

```
li:before {
  content: "\00BB";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}
```