# Clean text wrapping using custom <ul> bullets with pseudo class

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How can I ensure the `<li>` text is properly indented (see problem third from bottom) when using custom bullet points with empty psuedo element

[image]

```css
  ul {
      list-style: none;
      li {
        position: relative;
        span {
          font-size: 14px;
          line-height: 22px;
          font-weight: $fw-bold;
          margin: 4px 0;
        }
        &:before {
          content:'';
          display: inline-block;
          height: 11px;
          width: 4px;
          background-color: rgba(254, 80, 0, 0.4);
          margin-right: 16px;
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Application individuelle pour les joueurs</span></li>
  <li><span>Accès Dashboard centralisé pour les coachs</span></li>
  <li><span>Formation initiale (VFC + inCORPUS)</span></li>
  <li><span>2 interventions thématiques d'1 jour</span></li>
  <li><span>Accompagnement expert toute l’année</span></li>
  <li><span>Nombre illimité de check-ups à distance</span></li>
  <li><span>Gestion autonome des équipes</span></li>
  <li><span>Paramétrage de l’accès aux résultats des tests pour les joueurs</span></li>
  <li><span>Cardio-fréquencemètres inCORPUS</span></li>
  <li><span>Assistance technique au quotidien</span></li>
</ul>
```

I also tried `text-indent: -1em;` per the solution below but it only works if there is text content in `content: ''`

[Custom ul bullet with pseudo-selector and alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465257/custom-ul-bullet-with-pseudo-selector-and-alignment)

Comment: check *all* the answers, there is solution without text-indent

Comment: I had tried them it - it turns out the `text-indent` needed to be placed on the `<li>` and not the child `<span>`